# Consulta SQL WHERE primary_key = x

Tags: sql

Estuve buscando una forma para obtener una tupla donde su clave primaria sea igual al valor que le estoy pasando por parámetro, es decir:

```
SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE primary_key = 1;
```

O bien podría ser:

```
SELECT * FROM boletas WHERE primary_key = 'boleta1';
```

La cosa es que **no sé de ante mano cual es la primary key, ni su tipo, pero sé que el parámetro para evaluar va a ser correcto**.

Además necesitaría una sentencia SQL ya que las que encontré son de MySQL (por ej. `SHOW KEYS FROM clientes WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY'`) o SQL Server, lo que necesito es algo propio del SQL nativo, que cualquier DBMS pueda entender, ya que el sistema podría tener que enfrentarse con cualquiera.

¿Es posible hacer esto?

Comment: eh.. no.. porque ya viste que lo que es estandar para una no es estandar para otra.. y sql define el estandar de consulta, no el estandar de como guardar los datos.. y es mas.. yo te diria.. y si te encuentras con un teradata? que no tiene primary key??

Comment: en mysql se puede averiguar la key de una tabla con la instruccion **select COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name ='nombre_tabla' and column_key = 'PRI';**, pero creo que esto no es del estandar.

Comment: Hola @gbianchi, gracias por responder, pero las DB con las que estamos trabajando todas tienen PK y se manejan así, ya queda fuera de nuestro control

Comment: Gracias por responder @AngelCid, como dices, en SQL Server esa consulta ya no funciona :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No creo que exista una forma "ANSI" de llegar a dicha información, cada motor implementa formas distintas de acceder a dichos datos, en una época SQL Server por ejemplo,  te ofrecía y recomendaba el uso de unos Sp´s `sp_help_*`, con el tiempo se fueron estandarizando esos datos en tablas o vistas del motor por lo que recuperar esos datos se puede hacer con una simple consulta SQL, es decir tenes variantes entre motores y también entre versiones de un mismo motor. Como ya te comentó @CharlieBits, necesitarías una capa de abstracción es decir un [ORM](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapeo_objeto-relacional) para poder estandarizar tu código. De todas formas, a modo de ejemplo, si te sirve, te paso un ejemplo en SQL 2012:

```
SELECT  
    o.name, 
    i.name,
    i.is_primary_key, 
    c.name,
    t.name
    FROM sys.indexes i
    INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ic
        ON ic.object_id = i.object_id
        AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c
        ON c.object_id = i.object_id
        AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
    INNER JOIN sys.types t
        on t.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
    INNER JOIN sys.objects o
        ON o.object_id = i.object_id
    ORDER BY 1
```

Agregando el WHERE adecuado podes saber de una tabla cual es la clave primaria (si la tiene) la o las columnas que compone dicho índice y el tipo de dato de cada una de ellas.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta! Como dice Charlie voy a tener que implementarlo desde el lenguaje de programación que estoy utilizando. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

No sé si entiendo bien tu pregunta, pero básicamente conozco 2 dialectos SQL que son: `PL SQL` (típico de Oracle) y `TRANSACT SQL` que es la variante usada por SQL Server o MySQL entre otros. A su vez, cada implementación tiene variantes en términos que no son del corpus común del lenguaje.
De todos modos, la consulta que quieres hacer debería poder ser interpretada por cualquiera de las variantes. El único problema está en el tipo de dato porque hasta donde yo conozco, todas las variantes tratarán de diferenciar entre uno de los tipos `string` y uno de los tipos `number`.

Entonces, si el parámetro que le pasas debe ser un número, no debe ir entrecomillado en la sentencia SQL. Si es una cadena, sí.
Vale decir, en el caso de que el `ID` sea el número 1, pero el tipo es cadena:

```
SELECT * FROM boletas WHERE primary_key = '1';
```

Para el caso en donde el `ID` es 1 y el tipo es numérico:

```
SELECT * FROM boletas WHERE primary_key = 1;
```

Comment: Hola! Gracias por responder, pero lo que necesito es obtener ese primary_key, si mi PK en boletas es "Nombre_boletas" hacer una consulta que me retorne ese nombre, en el caso de clientes "id" y así

Comment: Si necesitas estar libre del motor de base de datos vas a necesitar hacerlo desde el lenguaje de programación. En Java por ejemplo, tenes tecnologías como JPA y Hibermate que te permiten desligarte de la base de datos y que usan un lenguaje comun y luego traducen ese comando a sql del motor en el que esten trabajando. Con esas tecnologías desde el lenguaje de programación obtendría el o los campos de la clave y harias lo qie necesitas. Desde sql no creo que haya forma de hacerlo para todolos motores por igual.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta @CharlieBits! Al final voy a tener que hacer como decís, en este caso tendré que vérmelas con Java! Saludos!